# Dataflow job with ProfileOptions profile_cpu=True not writing profile files

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to profile the CPU usage of a Dataflow Pipeline job, run on Apache Beam Python 3.7 SDK 2.27.0. I triggered the job with the `--profile_cpu` and `profile_location` args set, and can see that they are set in the Dataflow console:

[Dataflow Pipeline Options showing that profile_cpu and profile_location are set.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C20GI.png)

However, after the job completed there were no files written to the `profile_location` GSC bucket.

When looking at the Dataflow logs with `jsonPayload.logger:"apache_beam.utils.profiler:profiler.py"` I can see the logs that say "Start profiling" and "Stop profiling":

[Logs showing the "Start profiling" and "Stop profiling" messages from the `Profiler`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EolaP.png)

but there are no logs corresponding to the "Copying profiler data to:" step even though the `profile_location` is set in the `ProfilingOptions` and therefore should be set on the `Profiler`. Any advice on what could be going wrong, or knowledge of whether this functionality is currently supported would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you try running with Dataflow Runner v2? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-runner-v2

Comment: Yes this worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by using the `--experiments=use_runner_v2` flag. Looks like this is only supported on Dataflow Runner v2, which has not been rolled out as the default runner yet.